# In XSLT can I tokenize on nothing?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to convert the string 'abcdef' to its parts, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'. Stupidly I tried
    tokenize('abcdef', '')
but of course that returns a FORX0003 error (The regular expression in tokenize() must not be one that matches a zero-length string).

I'm actually trying to convert the string finally to 'a/b/c/d/e/f' so any shortcuts that would get me directly to this state would also be useful.

(I'm using Saxon 9.3 for .NET platform)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this line:

```
replace(replace($input, "(.)", "$1/", "s"), "(.*).$", "$1", "s")
```

Where `$input` points at your original string. The return of this line is your desired string.

```
a/b/c/d/e/f
```

Answer (score 5):

**To get the desired character sequence from a string `$str` use the pair of functions [`string-to-code-points()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-to-codepoints) and [`codepoints-to-string()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-codepoints-to-string)**:

```
for $c in string-to-codepoints($str)
 return
    codepoints-to-string($c)
```

To get this character sequence joined with '/' as the join-string, simply apply **[`string-join()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-join)** on the above expression.

**Here is a full code example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:sequence select=
      "string-join(
              for $c in string-to-codepoints('ABC')
              return
                 codepoints-to-string($c),
            '/'
                     )
      "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**produces the wanted character sequence**:

```
A/B/C
```

**Explanation**:

`string-to-codepoints($str)` produces a sequence of code-points (think of them as "character codes") representing each character of the string.

**For example**;

```
string-to-codepoints('ABC')
```

**produces the sequence**:

```
65 66 67

codepoints-to-string($code-seq)
```

is the inverse function of `string-to-codepoints()`. Given a sequence of codepoints, it produces the string, whose characters are represented by the codepoints in the sequence. Thus:

```
codepoints-to-string((65,66,67))
```

produces the string:

```
ABC
```

Therefore:

```
for $c in string-to-codepoints($str)
 return
    codepoints-to-string($c)
```

gets the codepoint of each individual character in `$str` and converts it to a *separate* string.

Using `string-join()` we then join all such separate strings using the provided join-character "/".

Comment: This solution works perfectly but I've accepted FailedDev's answer as it is shorter and slightly easier for (simple) people (like me) to understand